# "Visitor Conversion" types of questions.

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

During our [definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters/969#969), we deemed [questions like this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/earn-through-personal-blog-site-closed) to be off topic for our site.

I'd like to ask the community which of the following courses of action would be most appropriate:

1. Allow these types of questions, make them CW and see 'where it goes'
2. Specifically disallow these types of questions in our FAQ

I'm inclined to stick with what was decided in the definition phase unless there is a *compelling* reason to re-visit decisions that we, as a community made prior to the private beta.

Additionally, we're already granting quite a bit of latitude when it comes to questions that ask for opinions, lists or polls.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say either way since there seems to be no reasoning as to why these sorts of questions would be off topic, just unanimous opposition.

I can see where allowing any question of this sort could lead to a lot of spam, but I can also see where there could be 'real' questions buried within some of these topics outside of the 'tell me how to make money' type.  Other SEO type questions were deemed on topic, I'm not sure that there's a completely clear separation between SEO and 'Visitor Conversion'.

So to conclude: I think to answer this question we need to make explicit why the convert site visits to income question you linked to is off topic but [this AdSense question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters/898#898) and [this SEO question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters/924#924) are on topic.  What are the significant differences between the three in subject matter, intent and wording?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is on topic.

I also think the question should be Community Wiki for 3 reasons.

1. The question can be answered many ways and the answers have to deal more with creativity and a list of options/choices rather than any kind of solutions that will solve/answer the question
2. The question and answers could be a lightning rod for positive or negative votes depending on where the answers go.
3. The question is good but could be even better if it was less specific.  I think it would be great to hear what solutions have worked for people across the range of blog sizes.  People like Jeff Atwood could give great info on what works for larger blogs as well and other could give info on what worked for them at different sizes.